# Como arreglar el select html para que quede bien el formulario?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un form pero por alguna razon el select me descuadra el input de abajo y no se como hacer para que quede bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui les pongo el codigo:

html:

```
<div id="register_new_product" v-if = "hide == true">
        <section class = "register_product">
            <div class = "blocks">   
                <label class = "register_new_product_label">Product type:</label>
                <select class = "register_new_product_select" v-model="type"><option value="syrup">Syrup</option><option value="pills">Pills</option><option value="capsules">Capsules</option><option value="cream">Cream</option><option value="other">Other</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class = "blocks">
                <label class = "register_new_product_labelt" >Product's name:</label>
                <input class = "register_new_product_input" type="text" name="name" v-model="name"/>
            </div>
            <div class = "blocks">
                <label class = "register_new_product_labelt">Quantity per box:</label>
                <input class = "register_new_product_input" type="text" name="quantity_box" v-model="quantity_box"/>
            </div>
            <div class = "blocks">
                <label class = "register_new_product_labelt">Boxes per pallet:</label>
                <input class = "register_new_product_input" type="text" name="box_pallet" v-model="box_pallet"/>
            </div>
            <div class = "blocks">
                 <button @click = "registerproduct" type="button"> Register new product</button>
           </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.blocks {
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.register_new_product_label {
display: inline-block;
text-align: right;
float: left;
}

.register_new_product_input {
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
float: right;  
width: 50%;  
}


.register_new_product_select {
float: right; 
width: 50%;
}
```

estoy jugando con los valores pero no encuentro forma de que el products's name quede normal, ademas, hay alguan forma de que el label y el input no esten tan alejados uno del otro? gracias :)

Comment: Si no me equivoco tienes código de Vue.js ahi, pudieras usar las facilidades de la tecnología y probar. Dale un vistazo a esto: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form

Comment: si, pero quiero hacerlo primero con css puro y luego meterme con los frameworks, mi orgullo no me deja xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré el fallo, en el atributo class del label del nombre

```
<label class = "register_new_product_labelt" >Product's name:</label>
```

La clase le sobra la t del final, es

```
"register_new_product_label"
```